# Pillow in Python won't let me open image ("exceeds limit")

Tags: python, image, dataset

Just having some problems running a simulation on some weather data in Python. The data was supplied in a .tif format, so I used the following code to try to open the image to extract the data into a numpy array.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('jan.tif')
```

But when I run this code I get the following error:

```
PIL.Image.DecompressionBombError: Image size (933120000 pixels) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.
```

It looks like this is just some kind of protection against this type of attack, but I actually need the data and it is from a reputable source. Is there any way to get around this or do I have to look for another way to do this?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Try

```
PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 933120000
```

How to find out such a thing?

```
import PIL
print(PIL.__file__)  # prints, e. g., /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py
```

Then

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL
grep -r -A 2 'exceeds limit' .
```

prints

```
./Image.py:            "Image size (%d pixels) exceeds limit of %d pixels, "
./Image.py-            "could be decompression bomb DOS attack." %
./Image.py-            (pixels, MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS),
```

Then

```
grep -r MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS .
```

prints

```
./Image.py:MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = int(1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 4 / 3)
./Image.py:    if MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS is None:
./Image.py:    if pixels > MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS:
./Image.py:            (pixels, MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS),
```

Then

```
python3
import PIL.Image
PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 933120000
```

Works without complaint and fixes your issue.

Comment: If you 100% trust your inputs, you can also disable the check completely with `PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None`

Answer (score 74):

After the imports, add :

```
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
```

Comment: Dude, you are great

Comment: sometimes comparisons doing this would fail the conditions such as `if w*h > Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS:` with an error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Answer (score 1):

PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None ,
instead of this use
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
this is working fine

Comment: This answer is already there.