# (VScode) Jupyter Kernel crushes with pillow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I want to do a very simple operation: I want to save `.emf` files into `.png`. To do so I do:

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL 

path_img = './' + title + ".png"
Image.open(file).save(path_img)
```

This has always worked. However, today I encountered an image that exceeds the pixel limit:
`PIL.Image.DecompressionBombError: Image size (933120000 pixels) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.`

So I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152059/pillow-in-python-wont-let-me-open-image-exceeds-limit) on SoF which suggests to do the following:

```
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
```

However, when I do this I got the following error:

`Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.`

I do not understand why I got it. I [read](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Kernel-crashes) that this is typically due to incorrectly installed packages. Indeed, I tried to do upgrade the Pillow package with pip but it did not work.

Does anyone know how to handle this issue?